# RabbitMQ symfony doctrine always return the same result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, rabbitmq

I test RabbitMQ on my symfony project.
My POC does something really simple, when I update a translation I want to rebuild the cache.
The building of the cache is made by the rabbitMQ consumer.

Everything work except one thing : I always get the same doctrine result.

For exemple if I update "hello world" translation by "Hi all" it is correctly updated in DB, I send a message to consumer for update the cache, the consumer get the new translation in DB and ... this is the old translation that returned.

I run rabbitMQ with this command : `php app/console rabbitmq:consumer store_in_cache`

If I restart the process it work for the first message, but not for the next messages.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: It is hard to say something without seing a piece of code but you can look http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/rabbitmq for symfony+RabbitMQ examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution, I must to clear the entity manager.
It work like a charm now.